# Not able to connect to JMS server via SSL in JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jms

I'm testing SSL JMS queue server in JMeter using JMS publisher and subscriber. I have provided the URL `ssl://xxx:xxxx`, but when I run the test it is trying to connect via TCP and throwing below error:

```
Response message: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to query JNDI: Failed to connect to the server at tcp://xxx:xxxx [Root exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to connect to the server at tcp://xxx:xxxx]
```

Can anybody help with what properties/libraries I need to add, where to add?

Below is the configuration related to Publisher in JMeter:
[Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD9o6.png)

I need to connect via SSL.

Comment: What JMS broker are you attempting to connect to? Client libraries and URL configuration is usually based on which broker you're connecting to. How is JMeter configured to connect? Is it using JNDI?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to tibco JMS queue, I have configured it in JMeter via publisher and subscriber. Below is the configuration related to publisher:
Initial Context Factory - com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory,
Provide URL: ssl://localhost:7243,
Connection Factory - SSLConnectionFactory,
Destination - QUEUE_NAME

Comment: Please add these details _to your question_ or it will be closed for lack of detail.